# How to handle dropdown-cell in ReactGrid?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-grid-layout

How to handle so that each select can have its own value in cell? I use ReactGrid and react version 16 
it seems there is an error in the onchange, but no one can help me with this

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { ReactGrid, Column, Row, CellChange } from "@silevis/reactgrid";
import "@silevis/reactgrid/styles.css";
import "./styles.css";

const getColumns = (): Column[] => [
  { columnId: "col-1", width: 150 },
  { columnId: "col-2", width: 150 }
];

const headerRow: Row = {
  rowId: "header",
  cells: [
    { type: "header", text: "Dropdown:" },
    { type: "header", text: "Data:" }
  ]
};

const getRows = (isDropdownOpened: boolean): Row[] => [
  headerRow,
  {
    rowId: "row-1",
    cells: [
      {
        type: "dropdown",
        values: [
          { value: "react", label: "React" },
          { value: "vue", label: "Vue" },
          { value: "angular", label: "Angular" }
        ],
        isOpen: isDropdownOpened
        // isDisabled: false,
        // selectedValue: "react",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    rowId: "row-2",
    cells: [
      {
        type: "dropdown",
        values: [
          { value: "react", label: "React" },
          { value: "vue", label: "Vue" },
          { value: "angular", label: "Angular" }
        ],
        isOpen: isDropdownOpened
        // isDisabled: false,
        // selectedValue: "vue",
      }
    ]
  }
];

function App() {
  const [isDropdownOpened, setIsDropdownOpened] = React.useState(false);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState<
    string | undefined
  >();

  const handleChanges = (changes: CellChange[]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(changes) && changes.length > 0) {
      changes.forEach((change) => {
        if (change.newCell && change.newCell.type === "dropdown") {
          if (change.newCell.isOpen !== isDropdownOpened) {
            setIsDropdownOpened(change.newCell.isOpen);
          }
          // updating the value of a selected option
          if (change.newCell.selectedValue !== selectedValue) {
            setSelectedValue(change.newCell.selectedValue);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };

  const rows = getRows(isDropdownOpened);
  const columns = getColumns();

  return (
    <>
      <ReactGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} onCellsChanged={handleChanges} />
      <h3>You selected: {selectedValue || "none"}</h3>
    </>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

really can if someone wants to do custom on the code
looks simple but the documentation for this is very lacking

really can if someone wants to do custom on the code
looks simple but the documentation for this is very lacking

really can if someone wants to do custom on the code
looks simple but the documentation for this is very lacking

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define an array state that holds each row's values.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{ rowId: 0 , isOpen: false, selectedValue: 'react'...}, ...])
```

On the handler function then updates the data that has changed and sets the values. But you need to regenerate the new rows based on the new data.

But it appears the dropdown change handler doesn't work properly, it fires many times when you open the dropdown and choose the option, then fires again when closed and the selected value or value returns undefined. As you said the docs are not clear and it seems you need to find a way to make it to work properly.